# Realtime data transfer between two or more Oracle databases

Tags: database, oracle, batch-file, oracle10g, file-transfer

Currently we have four applications runnings on either Oracle 10g or 9i and use OAQ for data transfer but Oracle Streams for within day data transfer.  Streams is currently viewed as bringing tight coupling between the applications and such will not be our method of choice going forward.

What I would like to know is

1. is the assumption about streams correct ?
2. what other methods or tools should be considered to replace this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the  [Oracle distributed Database capabilities](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14231/ds_concepts.htm#i1007500)

Comment: External tables are for importing the data into Oracle DB, they're not used for replicating data between multiple instances.

Answer (score 0):

> Streams is currently viewed as bringing tight coupling between the applications

I would disagree with this statement. Streams is a mechanism of replicating **data**, the same data can be used in various ways by different applications. Can you elaborate more why you reached this conclusion.

An alternative to Streams is Oracle MView Replication or Advanced Replication, but nowadays Streams is the de facto standard as it does not require direct DB-to-DB links, i.e. it can run over HTTP. If some of the applications are read-only, you could also consider Active Data Guard (which again uses Streams for replication).

Comment: Thanks - I've never really got to the bottom of why this is considered as a tight coupling tech by memebers within the company.  At least this has reinforced my views.  This may be a stupid question but as Streams can run over http I assume then that this is still a viable option across datacentres - regardless of location?

Comment: That's correct, in fact Oracle Data Guard runs on top of Streams and is designed for disaster recovery, i.e. site failure.